# how to check my created item y coordinate against my wrapper height?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**What I am trying to do:**
Create item within my wrapper

**What is actually happening:**
Created item can go beyond my wrapper

This is my wrapper code

```
 <div className="DetailLocationContainer">
       
 </div>
```

my css

```
.DetailLocationContainer {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  /* margin: 2% auto auto auto; */
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(#ccc 0 1px, transparent 1px 100%),
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #ccc 0 1px, transparent 1px 100%);
  background-size: 50px 50px;
}
```

This is my create item code

```
 createElement(el) {
    const i = el.add ? "+" : el.i;
    var test = document.getElementById("hello");
    if (test != null) {
      //  test.getAttribute("style")

      var testing = test.style.transform.replace(/[\(\)]/g, "").split(",")[1];
      console.log("testing ", testing);

      if (testing === "300px") {
        alert("it works");
      }
    }
    return <div key={i} data-grid={el} id="hello"></div>;
  }
```

even when the created element exceed the height of my wrapper, it did not enter my if condition

This is my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-grid-layout-forked-enh81?file=/src/styles.css)

Answer (score 0):

the easy solution would be to add `overflow: hidden;` to `DetailLocationContainer` This would hide the overflowing content, but it would still "overflow." You could try to read the sum of the parent divs x coordinate and height, to compare with your child div. But in my opinion that wouldn't result in a cleaner solution.

(i'm not familiar enough with react, to know how you would get access, to your parent div in your js)

Comment: i have manage to get the transform translate of my created element  but it did not enter my if condition, click the link in my question for my updated codesandbox